# Queue multiple urls in video view

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Can we queue multiple video url's on start, which will play video one by one and will stream next video in advance.

E.g. if i give 10 URL's then it will start with 1st one and will stream 2nd one in advance so it will be played smoothly.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

ExoPlayer has a `ConcatenatingMediaSource`that enables sequential playback of URL's for example

```
MediaSource firstSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(firstVideoUri, ...);
MediaSource secondSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(secondVideoUri, ...);
// Plays the first video, then the second video.
ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource =
new ConcatenatingMediaSource(firstSource, secondSource);
```